# Find all functional dependencies

Tags: sql, database-normalization

I have a long exercise and everything relies on the first part which is listing all the functional dependencies. But this is so ambiguous — can you help me listing them?  I did something, of course, but I feel like it's not enough.

Here are my FDs:

```
SocialIN -> EmpName
ProjectID -> ProjectName
ProjectID -> Location
```

I will have to turn it into BCNF afterwards, so I don't want to miss anything. I can't find a Dependency for hours. Am I missing some? Did I put something useless?

[image: Table with columns SocialIN, ProjectID, Hours, EmpName, ProjectName, Location]

Comment: SocialIN, ProjectID -> Hours?

Comment: Obviously not! 987, 30 -> 5;    987, 30 -> 20 so contradiction here

Comment: Is there a typo in the data? SocialIN 987 gives you both 'Giroux, Jill' and 'Williams, Tot'. If the data is correct, then SocialIN->EmpName is wrong.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in the data, the SocialIN value 987 maps to both "Giroux, Jill" and "Williams, Tot", so the SocialIN ⟶ EmpName FD is incorrect if the data is correct. In fact, I think the data in the table/image is erroneous. Most likely, there is a mistake and Jill and Tot should have different SocialIN values. And then, as [Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562459/mike-sherrill-cat-recall) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723864/find-all-functional-dependencies#comment47582678_29723864), the {SocialIN, ProjectID} ⟶ Hours FD should hold.

However, assuming that the data is correct, then the FD EmpName ⟶ SocialIN holds (rather than the reverse FD), and the FD {EmpName, ProjectID} ⟶ Hours holds.

Not only does the FD ProjectID ⟶ ProjectName hold in the data, but ProjectName ⟶ ProjectID also holds in the data shown.  Given this, ProjectName ⟶ Location also holds, and so does {EmpName, ProjectName} ⟶ Hours.

There are also multiple trivial FDs that aren't worth pointing out (such as EmpName ⟶ EmpName).

Hence, I think the complete set of non-trivial FDs in the data given is:

- EmpName ⟶ SocialIN
- ProjectID ⟶ ProjectName
- ProjectID ⟶ Location
- ProjectName ⟶ ProjectID
- ProjectName ⟶ Location
- {EmpName, ProjectName} ⟶ Hours
- {EmpName, ProjectID} ⟶ Hours

If the mapping for Gill and Tot is incorrect and they have separate SocialIN values, then you can add:

- SocialIN ⟶ EmpName
- {SocialIN, ProjectName} ⟶ Hours
- {SocialIN, ProjectID} ⟶ Hours

Comment: Yes; the arrows are very directional.  Witness the data in the table as it stands (putatively erroneous)...the EmpName ⟶ SocialIN because each name is associated with exactly one SocialIN.  As it stands, though, the converse doesn't apply because one SocialIN is associated with two different names.  Or, more generally (and without having to debate the validity of the data), ProjectName ⟶ Location but Location does not determine ProjectName.